# docker swarm services are restarting automatically

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We are running a **docker swarm cluster** with 3 managers and 5 workers. Twice now we have experienced some error in the cluster where **every service is restarted automatically**.

This happens when the heartbeat is getting failed. The service `4adb11869318` on manager node and the service `e7b284330420` on worker node had the issues very frequently

Manager Node Logs: https://pastebin.com/YdriawA6

Worker Node Logs: https://pastebin.com/AvGCstfg

I dont know how to prevent the restart of docker services. Do you have any suggestions?